# Can I reuse transformations related code with GLSL?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I had an old OpenGL project that did not involve GLSL, and now
I rewrite it so that it uses GLSL. I have a function that rotates
the camera around a fixed point when you move the mouse. I am not sure
how to use this function in my new project, now that I use GLSL and
not the standard OpenGL fixed pipeline.

This is the function, and I am not sure if I can use the same code
or will I have to rewrite the transformations so that it works for GLSL?

```
void mouseMovePassive(int x, int y)
{
    static int oldX=x, oldY=y;

    rotateCamera(y-oldY, x-oldX);

    int centerX = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH )/2;
    int centerY = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT )/2;
    if( abs(centerX-x) > 250 || abs(centerY-y) > 250 )
    {
        glutWarpPointer(centerX, centerY);
        oldX = centerX;
        oldY = centerY;
    }
    else
    {
        oldX = x;
        oldY = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: The interesting function would be `rotateCamera` not your input event handler. Please post the source code of that one. Right now we can't help you, due to lack of information.

Comment: There's not enough information here to be able to answer this question. We can only guess at what those functions actually do.

Comment: Hi guys. The code kinda goes deep, too much to bother you with, but in the end it gets down to a call to gluLookAt. So I guess my real question now is, what do I do with that gluLookAt call, how do I rewrite such a call in GLSL. Can i reuse it?

Answer (score 2):

As far as Im aware, gluLookAt works on the built-in matrix types. For newer versions over opengl you will either need to re-write it or use a third party library. If you're using c++ I believe the glm library has it built in